# Is there a good embedded system that can run Linux?

Tags: linux, embedded

I remember one such popular hardware. It was small, had USB ports, etc. and could run some descent Linux. I can't recall its name at all. It is like Arduino, but only more powerful.

My requirement is to have a small system that is capable of connecting to Wifi network and can run a program which can receive and send HTTP packets.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247/how-do-i-get-started-in-embedded-programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) .

**EDIT**

Also checkout this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3345/beagleboard-alternatives) on electronics.se

Comment: BeagleBoard is quite an overkill, but IGEPv2 looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Any ARM9, 11 or Cortex-A class board with sufficient memory will run Linux, as will any Atom or embedded PC board. A lower-end ARM7 with sufficient memory will run uClinux without MMU support (which kind of misses the point of using Linux IMO).

There are many such boards from many suppliers.  Try Googling "embedded linux development board" for example.

You'll need at least 4Mb of Flash (or the ability to bootload from a memory card or other mass storage device), and 16Mb RAM for a basic Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

There's the [Beagle Board](http://beagleboard.org/), or is that too much overkill for what you're thinking?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Computer on Modules](http://www.gumstix.com/store/index.php?cPath=27)  by [GumStix](http://www.gumstix.com). I remember them having enclosures but it has been years since last seeing them.

On a separate note I think you would find the ZigBee device XBee to be also interesting there are different types.

Additional Links:
[Gumstix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumstix)
[Wiki Page](http://docwiki.gumstix.org/index.php/Main_Page)
RIP: [Netstix](http://docwiki.gumstix.org/index.php/Netstix) and [Way Smalls](http://docwiki.gumstix.org/index.php/Waysmalls)

Answer (score 0):

Many people have had a lot of success using standard [WiFi Access Points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point) that can find online for $20 or so. It will be hard to find any other system with WiFi at a lower price.

Combined with open-source Linux router projects like [OpenWRT](http://www.openwrt.org) and [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com), you have a low powered, embedded Linux device.

Comment: Both of them are firmwares, not hardware.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was clear what hardware I was referencing. I'll add some additional clarity.